# Every monotonic function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

In my script there is a proof for „ Every monotonic function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable“, I don‘t understand.

> Let $a\in \mathbb{R}$. We want to show $A=\{ x\in \mathbb{R} |f\left(x\right) >a\}$ is measurable (which is equivalent to $f$ is measurable).
>   Let f be increasing. Is $f\left( x\right) >a$ and $y\geq x$, then $f\left( y\right) \geq f\left( x\right) >a$. Thus $A$ is an interval either of the form $[ c,\infty [$ or $] c, \infty[$, thus measurable.

What i don‘t understand is, why does $A$ have to be an interval?
Isn‘t $A$ only an interval, if $f$ is continuous?

On the same page there is another statement, without proof.

> A monotonic function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is integrable, iff $f\left( x\right) =0$ for almost every $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Is there a simple proof for that?

Comment: They just showed that if $x\in A$ and $y\geq x$, then $y\in A$. Then, either $A$ is empty or let $c$ be the infimum of $A$. Then elements of $]c,+\infty[$ are in $A$. The point $c$ may or may not be in $A$.

Comment: For the second statement, assume that $f$ takes some positive value $f(x_0)>0$ (if not just work with $-f$). Then $f^+\geq f(x_0)\chi_{[x_0,a]}$ for all $a>x_0$, where $\chi_{[x_0,a]}$ is the characteristic function of $[x_0,a]$ and $f^+=\max(f,0)$. Now observe that $\int f(x_0)\chi_{[x_0,a]}=f(x_0)(a-x_0)$, which can be made as large as you want by taking $a$ arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice The intervals $[c,\infty[$ or $]c,\infty[$ are on domain, NOT in range. And $y$ can take any real greater than $x$. So they produce an interval in domain, without need to continuity ,as claimed.